# How can I find out how my VPS was penetrated?

Tags: server, ssh, hacking

I have a VPS, running Ubuntu.
Recently I found out that the VPS was hacked and someone put a script on all the websites hosted on the VPS.

Sucuri says it is a MW:SPAM:SEO. I cleaned up the VPS, but I am wondering how the VPS was penetrated!

The only open ports on the VPS are 22 and 80.
I have disabled password auth for SSH and only use public key auth, and I am the only one who has access to the VPS.

Is there anyway I can find out about this?

EDIT

Most of the web applications are Wordpress instances. I am using Nginx with php5-fpm.

Comment: You could research Blackhat SEO Spam to possibly determine how it works or perhaps consult with the security experts at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

SSH authentication attempts are typically stored in the /var/log/auth.log file. So there might be something useful in there if the attacker got access via SSH.

Most likely though, it's a vulnerability in one of your web applications which allowed the attacker access. Now you don't mention what web server stack you use, or what kinds of applications you run, so it's hard to be specific. But in general you should comb through the web server logs and look for suspicious entries.

And if you run things like WordPress, you should make sure it's up-to-date and update all plugins. In the case of WordPress it's often a badly written plugin which allows the attacker to take control over your server.